# Windows batch file timestamp to string

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following simple line in my windows batch file to get the current time stamp to a String format so that I can use it later in the batch file to create a folder with same name.

```
set TIME_STAMP=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
```

I observed that when the time is single digits, say 9:31 AM, I get the String like this:

```
08-10-2015_ 9.31.52.57
```

Notice the space between the characters _ and 9.
When the system time is say 10:31 AM, it all works fine, like

```
08-10-2015_10.31.52.57
```

Is there something I can do to make the time stamp as

```
08-10-2015_09.31.52.57
```

when I have hours in single digits?

Comment: You could not have used that code to produce your result. You must have used `%TIME::=.%`

Comment: You already used `%var:search=replace%` to search and replace. Hmm, I wonder how you could convert a space into a zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Comment: dbenham has already stated how with humour :)

Answer (score 1):

just do this

```
set TIME_STAMP=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%
echo %TIME_STAMP: =0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simpliest approach:

```
set "TIME_STAMP=%DATE:/=-%_%TIME::=-%"
set "TIME_STAMP=%TIME_STAMP: =0%"
```

Result:

```
==> echo "%TIME_STAMP%"
"08.10.2015_07-42-08,18"

==>
```